# Slick support for google dataflow

Tags: java, scala, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Can we use slick to connect to database while in Google data flow? 
Or is it preferred to use JBBC IO only?

Also is there a way to handle async requests? like for example, mapasync in case of Akka Streams.

Answer (score 0):

Per current documentation (http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/supported-databases.html), Google data flow isn't supported.

Slick supports async requests pretty much everywhere by default I'd say, it'll give you nice Future to play with.